# WordPress 5.3 update with Enhanced Media Library (free or pro) causes media library file uploader to break due to a JavaScript error

Tags: javascript, wordpress, plugins

So after updating to WP 5.3 I can no longer use the file upload to choose files to add. I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at g.cleanup (backbone.min.js:1)
```

Error in console:
[image]

How it shows when I try to choose an image:
[image]

I have the Classic Editor plugin installed so I can use it the classic way. I have disabled all other unnecessary plugins but the problem still persists. It's only happened since the new WP core update to 5.3 yesterday.

Any ideas what's going on here?

Comment: I think you need roll back wordpress version and write issues on github.